# Split list in to multiple sublists based on counter value in Python

Tags: python

I can't seem to find an an answer for this, but I want to split a list in to multiple smaller lists based on a counter, so that the new list contains the same maximum number of values each time.

Once I have created a new sublist, I want to continue stepping through the original list to create a new sublist based on the next values.

```
keywordList = ["24/7 home emergency", "6 month home insurance", "access cover", "access insurance",
              "are gas leaks covered by home insurance", "central heating breakdown cover", "trace & access",
              "trace and access", "trace and access costs"]
maxLength = 4

for c, items in enumerate(keywordList):
    if c < maxLength:
        #append items to new list here
```

Expected output would be three new lists, first two four elements in length and the last one would be one element in length. But if the original list was suddenly to have 100 elements, we would get 25 new lists.

There seems to be information on splitting the original list evenly,  but nothing on a predetermined value. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output given your `keywordList` input?

Comment: I expect the output to be: 

`keywordList1 = ["24/7 home emergency", "6 month home insurance", "access cover", "access insurance"]
keywordList2 = ["are gas leaks covered by home insurance", "central heating breakdown cover", "trace & access", "trace and access"]
keywordList3 = ["trace and access costs"]`
to be repeated for as many keywords are in the original list i.e. if there was 100 keywords in original list we would end up with 25 sub lists.

Comment: Given that you don't know the length of the `keywordList`, you'd have to dynamically generate the list names. This is not what Python is built to do. The best way to accomplish what you're looking to do would be like the answers already provided.

Answer (score 1):

Edit to reflect your current question:

```
keywordList = ["24/7 home emergency", "6 month home insurance", "access cover", "access insurance",
              "are gas leaks covered by home insurance", "central heating breakdown cover", "trace & access",
              "trace and access", "trace and access costs"]

leng = len(keywordList)
keywordList += [""] * ((leng//4+1)*4 - leng)
result = [[keywordList[i] for i in range(j, j+4)] for j in range(0, leng, 4)]
result[-1] = [e for e in result[-1] if e]
```

`result`:

```
[['24/7 home emergency',
  '6 month home insurance',
  'access cover',
  'access insurance'],
 ['are gas leaks covered by home insurance',
  'central heating breakdown cover',
  'trace & access',
  'trace and access'],
 ['trace and access costs']]
```

The idea of this method is to pad the `keywordList` to a multiple of 4 with empty strings (could be anything) and then split by 4. After which clean the last element of empty strings (or whatever we decided to be representing empty object)

Comment: Sorry I dont think the question was clear, each new list should be four elements in length. So if we had original list with 100 elements we would end up with 25 new sublists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spit you list into multiple sublists you can use the following list comprehension:

```
from itertools import repeat, zip_longest

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

iter_l = iter(l)

[list(filter(None.__ne__, i)) for i in zip_longest(*repeat(iter_l, 4))]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: Does this create actual new lists that I can call from another function? So I see that it does split the elements, but ideally I would be able to then call the new lists as appropriate such as in `newList1 newList2 newList3`